# Need a query to get a list of used and unused tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I gave a list of tables from our schema in a text file to my boss asking him that we need **NOT** back up all these tables. Now he is asking me to write a query to return the rest of the tables which **REQUIRE BACK UP**.

He gave me the hint that I will have to use USER_TABS and DIFF in my query.

Can anybody please help?

I am using ORACLE database.

Answer (score 2):

What criteria defines a table that is "unused" and what criteria defines a table that "needs backup"?  And what do you mean by "backup"?

If you're talking about backups, you'd normally be talking about physical backups in which case you back up the entire database (either a full backup or an incremental backup depending on how you've structured your backup strategy).  You would not and could not include or exclude tables from a physical backup.  You could potentially move the tables to a read-only tablespace which lets Oracle know that they don't need to be backed up again.  But it doesn't sound like that's what you're after.

Comment: Hi Justin,

Our client wants to know the tables we are altering so that they dont have to unnecessarily take back up of all the tables every week. Rather, they just want to know the tables to which we have made changes  so that they can back up ONLY those tables and be good. The list of tables which I sent to my boss was manually made in Notepad

Comment: @Bhushan - Again, what do you mean by "backup"?  If you mean a normal physical backup, they should take an incremental RMAN backup and shouldn't need any input from you.  What do you mean by "altering"?  Do you really mean `ALTER TABLE` i.e. DDL?  Or do you mean tables that have DML changes?  Oracle does not track DML changes over arbitrary time periods-- if you really wanted to track every DML change to any table, you could potentially create triggers on every table that write to separate log tables and then query the log tables.  But that doesn't seem terribly practical.

Comment: ok, let me rephrase my question. Forget everything I said before. Now lets say I have 10 tables A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J.

Can you tell me a sql using USER_TABS and DIFF to return tables K to Z ?

Comment: @Bhushan - Assuming that K-Z exist and are the only other tables that exist `SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name NOT IN ('A','B','C','D',...,'J')`